# Groovy: how to insert a node at the beginning of a list of elements in XML read in using XMLSlurper()

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm probably missing something obvious, as I'm a noob with Groovy, but I've searched but haven't found quite what I'm looking for.  I have a test class where I'm reading in some XML; I want to insert an element **at the beginning** of a series of elements.  I have figured out how to *replace* the first element, and I've figured out how to *append* a node to the end of the list, but I can't seem to grok how to insert an element at the beginning of the list (or ideally, any arbitrary position).

For example:

```
@Test
void foo()
{
    def xml = """<container>
                   <listofthings>
                       <thing id="100" name="foo"/>
                   </listofthings>
                 </container>"""

    def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
    root.listofthings.thing[0].replaceNode ( { thing(id:101, name:'bar') })
    root.listofthings.appendNode  ( { thing(id:102, name:'baz') })

    def outputBuilder = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder()
    String result = outputBuilder.bind { mkp.yield root }
    print result
}
```

which yields:

```
<container>
   <listofthings>
     <thing id='101' name='bar'/>
     <thing id='102' name='baz'/>
   </listofthings>
</container>
```

What I really want is to insert a node at the **beginning** of *listofthings*,  i.e. something to replace the call to *replaceNode* that would instead insert the thing with id 101 before the thing with id 100.  I would also be nice if say, I had a longer list, to insert a node after the n'th element.

(Incidentally, is there a way to get the output in a more readable format?  The output from StreamingMarkupBuilder all ends up as a single line of text; I reformatted it for clarity above)

Edit: I'm using 1.7.5, that's bundled with Eclipse, if it matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way you can do this by extracting the `thing` elements out of your original xml into a list, manipulating the list, then rebuilding the document with this new list:

```
// function to take a single line xml output, and make it pretty
String renderFormattedXml( String xml ){
  def stringWriter = new StringWriter()
  def node = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )
  new XmlNodePrinter( new PrintWriter( stringWriter ) ).print( node )
  stringWriter.toString()
}

def xml = """<container>
               <listofthings>
                   <thing id="100" name="foo"/>
               </listofthings>
             </container>"""

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

def things = root.listofthings*.thing

// Insert one at pos 0
things.add( 0, { thing( id:98, name:'tim' ) } )

// And one at the end
things.add( { thing( id:999, name:'zebra' ) } )

// And one at position 1
things.add( 1, { thing( id:99, name:'groovy' ) } )

def outputBuilder = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder()
String result = outputBuilder.bind {
  container {
    listofthings {
      mkp.yield things
    }
  }
}
println renderFormattedXml( result )
```

which prints

```
<container>
  <listofthings>
    <thing id="98" name="tim"/>
    <thing id="99" name="groovy"/>
    <thing id="100" name="foo"/>
    <thing id="999" name="zebra"/>
  </listofthings>
</container>
```

Comment: When I tried running the code above, I got the name =fooand id =100 reversed in the output. Why?           
<container>
  <listofthings>
    <thing id="98" name="tim"/>
    <thing id="99" name="groovy"/>
    <thing name="foo" id="100"/>
    <thing id="999" name="zebra"/>
  </listofthings>
</container>