# Groovy: append an XML Node to an existing XML document

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm using Groovy and I'm trying to insert an xml node into a xml document parsed with XmlSlurper.
I manage to add the node at the end of the document but not where I really need to.

Original doc:

```
<xml-fragment xmlns:ser="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/pipeline/config"> 
    <ser:coreEntry isProxy="true" isEnabled="true" isTracingEnabled="false">
        <ser:binding type="SOAP" isSoap12="false" xsi:type="con:SoapBindingType" xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services/bindings/config">
          <con:wsdl ref="bus/src/main/osb/interfaces/apilink/ChargeServices"/>
          <con:port>
            <con:name>ChargeServicesPort</con:name>
            <con:namespace>java:dk.tdc.apilink.logic.sessions.interfaces</con:namespace>
          </con:port>
          <con:selector type="SOAP body"/>
        </ser:binding>
    </ser:coreEntry>
</xml-fragment>
```

Fragment to add

```
def fragmentToAddXml = '''
<ser:security xmlns:ser="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/pipeline/config">hello</ser:security>
'''
```

This is the code I'm using.

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(file.getText())

root.'core-entry'.appendNode( fragmentToAddXml )
def xmlBuilder = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind{ mkp.yield root }
```

Please note that the new node should be placed **before** the "ser:binding" node.

The result should be:

```
<xml-fragment xmlns:ser="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/pipeline/config"> 
        <ser:coreEntry isProxy="true" isEnabled="true" isTracingEnabled="false">
            <ser:security xmlns:ser="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/pipeline/config">hello</ser:security>

            <ser:binding type="SOAP" isSoap12="false" xsi:type="con:SoapBindingType" xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services/bindings/config">
              <con:wsdl ref="bus/src/main/osb/interfaces/apilink/ChargeServices"/>
              <con:port>
                <con:name>ChargeServicesPort</con:name>
                <con:namespace>java:dk.tdc.apilink.logic.sessions.interfaces</con:namespace>
              </con:port>
              <con:selector type="SOAP body"/>
            </ser:binding>
        </ser:coreEntry>
    </xml-fragment>
```

Thanks

Luciano

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given the xml (in a string for testing)

```
def xml = '''<xml-fragment xmlns:ser="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/pipeline/config"> 
    <ser:coreEntry isProxy="true" isEnabled="true" isTracingEnabled="false">
        <ser:binding type="SOAP" isSoap12="false" xsi:type="con:SoapBindingType" xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services/bindings/config">
          <con:wsdl ref="bus/src/main/osb/interfaces/apilink/ChargeServices"/>
          <con:port>
            <con:name>ChargeServicesPort</con:name>
            <con:namespace>java:dk.tdc.apilink.logic.sessions.interfaces</con:namespace>
          </con:port>
          <con:selector type="SOAP body"/>
        </ser:binding>
    </ser:coreEntry>
</xml-fragment>'''
```

And the xml you want to add as:

```
def toadd = '''<ser:security xmlns:ser="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/pipeline/config">
  hello
</ser:security>'''
```

Then you can parse them both (with `XmlSlurper` set to use namespaces via the 2nd `true` parameter)

```
def root = new XmlSlurper( false, true ).parseText( xml )
fragmentToAdd = new XmlSlurper( false, true ).parseText( toadd )
```

Append the xml to add to the `data` node (as you want it inside `data`, not `lastname`)

```
root.coreEntry.appendNode( fragmentToAdd )
```

Then print it out:

```
String outxml = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( root )
println outxml
```

Which prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-fragment>
  <ser:coreEntry xmlns:ser="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services" isTracingEnabled="false" isProxy="true" isEnabled="true">
    <ser:binding xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" isSoap12="false" xsi:type="SOAP">
      <con:wsdl xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services/bindings/config" ref="bus/src/main/osb/interfaces/apilink/ChargeServices"/>
      <con:port xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services/bindings/config">
        <con:name>ChargeServicesPort</con:name>
        <con:namespace>java:dk.tdc.apilink.logic.sessions.interfaces</con:namespace>
      </con:port>
      <con:selector xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services/bindings/config" type="SOAP body"/>
    </ser:binding>
    <ser:security>
    hello
  </ser:security>
  </ser:coreEntry>
</xml-fragment>
```

Which I believe is correct (not formatted 100% as I'd like, but correct) ;-)

#### Edit

If order is important, you can use `XmlParser` like so:

```
def root = new XmlParser( false, true ).parseText( xml )
fragmentToAdd = new XmlParser( false, true ).parseText( toadd )

// Insert this new node at position 0 in the children of the first coreEntry node
root.find { it.name() == 'ser:coreEntry' }.children().add( 0, fragmentToAdd )

String outxml = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( root )
println outxml
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Unfortunately I can't get it to work. I have omitted from my post that the xml I'm trying to manipulate has a bunch of Namespaces. It looks like
<abc:customer>
  <xyz:data>
...

Do you think it does make a difference? I thought that XMLSlurper was NS-agnostic.

Comment: @LucianoFiandesio Does that example code work if you just paste it into the groovy console?  If so, can you update your question so that it shows a more accurate piece of XML that fails to work, and I can have a go at getting it working :-)

Comment: Yes, your code example works perfectly, I'll update the question.

Comment: @LucianoFiandesio Just a simple failing example of xml will do :-)

Comment: @LucianoFiandesio Updated answer to match question...  Fingers crossed

Comment: almost there, thanks mate. I didn't know of the XmlSlurper constructor. The "security" node should be added before the "binding" element and after the "coreEntry" element (please, check the my question, I have added an example of how the final document should look like).

Comment: @LucianoFiandesio Heheh, been looking at this (as I guessed it was coming) ;-)  inserting at a given location is harder than appending... I'll have a think...

Comment: I think you have already replied :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525966/groovy-how-to-insert-a-node-at-the-beginning-of-a-list-of-elements-in-xml-read/6532853#6532853

Comment: @LucianoFiandesio Added a bit at the bottom using XmlParser to add the xml at the correct location :-)

Comment: Thanks Tim, the bit you have added throws:
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren.add() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer, groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild) values: [0,
  hello
]

I'm using the latest version of Groovy.

Comment: @LucianoFiandesio Odd...  sure you're doing: `root.find { it.name() == 'ser:coreEntry' }.children().add( 0, fragmentToAdd )` ?  It works for me (Groovy 1.8.3)

Comment: @LucianoFiandesio But that still uses `XmlSlurper`, not `XmlParser` as in my example code ;-)

Comment: @LucianoFiandesio hehe, no worries :-)  Happens to me all the time :-D

Comment: This code didnt work for me:  [Fatal Error] :2:4: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
ERROR:  'The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.'
Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 4; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.