# How to modify XML node value, when iterating through the file with XMLSlurper

Tags: xml, groovy

I am currently iterating through an XML file like this:

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

root.service.each { service ->
  service.receiver.endpoint.each { endpoint ->
    println "\t\tEndpoint: ${endpoint.text()}"
    }
}
```

I want to first read the endpoint.text() , and afterwards modify the value of the node, so the file contains a new value.
I am reading the node attributes fine, as it is. But how do I write to it afterwards?

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912987/groovy-append-an-xml-node-to-an-existing-xml-document), and understand how to write to an existing file. But what I am asking is, can it be done in a more elegant matter, when I am already iterating through the file to read some of it's content? I am hoping there is a more efficient way that suits the way I am iteraring through the file.

So am hoping there is a way to do something like this:

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

root.service.each { service ->
  service.receiver.endpoint.each { endpoint ->
    println "\t\tEndpoint: ${endpoint.text()}"
    // ****WRITE TO NODE****
    }
}
```

hope it makes sense.

Also, here is some example XML:

```
<project name='Common'>
  <service name='name' pattern='something' isReliable='maybe'>
    <receiver name='name' isUsingTwoWaySsl='maybe' isWsRmDisabled='maybe' 
       targetedByTransformation='maybe'>
      <endpoint name='local_tst01'>URL</endpoint>
      <endpoint name='local_tst02'>URL</endpoint>
      <endpoint name='local_tst03'>URL</endpoint>
      <environment name='dev' default='local_dev' />
      <environment name='tst01' default='test' />
      <environment name='tst02' default='local_tst02' />
    </receiver>
    <operation name='name'>
      <sender>sender</sender>
      <attribute name='operation' type='String'>name</attribute>
    </operation>
  </service>
</project>
```

Comment: sorry, the question is unclear - `I want to first read the endpoint.text() , and afterwards write to the node` -what do you mean?. Where are you  facing issue?

Comment: I am facing issues writing to the node? I don't know what courses misunderstandings. I would gladly edit to make it more clear.

Comment: You mean to say that url value needs to be changed for each of 3 occurrences in the above xml? Do you have the list of new values to be updated? Does the below answer helped ?

Comment: 1. Yes exactly, 2. Does that matter? Just insert "test" in them, 3. Yes, I am accepting that answer tomorrow if no other answer is submitted.

Comment: Jonas, thank for the details, see my answer if you think it suits your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't know why [`replaceBody`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/NodeChild.html#replaceBody-java.lang.Object-) method is protected but it works:

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(
'''<root>
    <service>
        <receiver>
            <endpoint>123</endpoint>
            <endpoint>456</endpoint>
        </receiver>
    </service>
</root>''')

root.service.each { service ->
    service.receiver.endpoint.each { endpoint ->
        endpoint.replaceBody("**"+endpoint.text())
    }
}

println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( root )
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the little variant to update the endpoints.

This is flexible so that you can choose what endpoint will need to have the new url as per the `name attribute` as defined in the below `endpointBinding` map. Of course, you can change the values as needed.

```
//Set your endpoint name attribute value and new endpoint url in a map
//This would be flexible to have the respective url
def endpointBinding = ['local_tst01': 'http://example01.com', 'local_tst02': 'http://example02.com', 'local_tst03': 'http://example03.com']

pXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

//Update the values in xml as per the binding defined above
endpointBinding.collect { k, v -> pXml.'**'.find{it.name() == 'endpoint' && it.@name == k }.replaceBody(v) }    

println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( pXml )
```

You can quickly try the same online <kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5197679093088256)</kbd>